# Configure inventory -> sources not showing in admin configuration 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, multi-source-inventory

i have upgraded Magento version from 2.2.10 to 2.3.3

And Now I am facing one problem in multi source inventory some configuration are missing.

- source configuration under inventory setting
- stock configuration under inventory setting
- product edit grid assign source option

Any Help will appreciate.

Comment: I am able to see this in Default Magento 2.3.3. Maybe there is some problem in your upgrade.